# Options of accessing wordpress data from mobile app

Tags: database, api, mobile

There is an existing wordpress website and I would like to make native app(probably will do crossplatform native with React Native as I have experience with it) for it. So my question is: is there an API or plugin that exposes API via which I could securely access wordpress data(posts, widgets/their data and etc.)?

Main reason is for admin of the website to post data once and have it on both, app and website.

Making Hybrid/Web app is declined, as app should feel and look native and all these wordpress to mobile plugins that "convert" website are not an option.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and/or links.

Comment: Have a look at the WP REST API

Comment: No problem. My pleasure

Comment: Did you get a solution to this. I also want to make a native mobile app (android / ios) to show content from a wordpress site.

Answer (score -1):

You can access WordPress data using WordPress [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). If you want to know how to use the REST API from a React Native app, then give a read to this [article](https://markuraine.com/creating-mobile-app-wp-api-react-native/).